# how to push the key value in empty object using es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

how to push the empty key value in empty object using es6

```
const obj={};
```

First I need to check the object is `isEmpty` or not then I need to push the key and value in that object.

```
if(Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
   const contArry = {"name": "xxx", "age": "0"};
}
```

i tried it but not working for me

My output must be `obj={"name": "xxx", "age": "0"}`

Comment: Have a look at [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
const obj = {};

if (!Object.keys(obj).length) {
    Object.assign(obj, { name: "xxx", age: "0" });
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

how to push the key value in empty object

```
var emp = {};
emp.name = "Steven";
emp.std = "12";
emp.sub = "CS";
emp.school = "LF"
console.log(emp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Object.assign:

```
 if(Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
    Object.assign(obj, {"name": "xxx", "age": "0"});
 }
```

or just:

```
 if(Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
     obj.name = "xxx";
     obj.age" = "0";
 }
```